# How to customise category top menu navigation by custom category id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category-tree, topmenu, category-navigation

By default Magento 2 showing the all store categories in top menu with a tree structure, I want to filter with custom category ids and only that filtered category need to show in category top menu navigation and rest will be removed.

Please help me to achieve this customization.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show particular categories in your menu navigation, just set the Include in Navigation Menu setting to 'No' for the categories you don't want to display.